# Which APIs are used by explorer.exe in Windows 7 to list files?

Tags: file, explorer

I am coding a rootkit-like program which hooks functions used by Windows to list files in a folder.
I know that in Windows XP explorer.exe uses `FindFirstFileW` / `FindNextFileW` each time we open/update directory, to list files that are contained in that folder.
Different story for Windows 7, and I can't manage to understand which functions are used here to do the job.

Comment: Look into the shell namespace API.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 windows explorer use IShellFolder
for every browse of specific directory it call to EnumObjects and from that return value it call to:

```
IEnumIDList::Next()
```