# Hook ishellfolder enumobjects

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-explorer

I am trying to hook the function enumobjects in Ishellfolder .
I am doing it because I want to display the user non existing files in explorer.
I was success to hook FindNextFile and FindFirstFile but unfortunately this function not always call by explorer according to this question [Which APIs are used by explorer.exe in Windows 7 to list files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694228/which-apis-are-used-by-explorer-exe-in-windows-7-to-list-files)

Now I try to hook IShellFolder::EnumObjects so I hook

```
MyCoCreateInstance(REFCLSID rclsid, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, DWORD dwClsContext, REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppv)
```

And inside this function I have the following code:

```
if (IsEqualCLSID(rclsid, (REFGUID) __uuidof (IShellFolder)) || 
    IsEqualCLSID(rclsid, (REFGUID) __uuidof (IShellFolder2)) ||
    IsEqualCLSID(rclsid, (REFGUID) CLSID_ShellDesktop) ||
    IsEqualCLSID(rclsid, (REFGUID) IID_IShellFolder) )
{

    PDEBUG(L"IID_IShellFolder.2");
    IShellFolderCast *shellFolder = (IShellFolderCast *) *ppv;

    orig_EnumObjects = (type_EnumObjects) GetInterfaceMethod(shellFolder->lpVtbl, 4);
    if (!Mhook_SetHook((void **) &orig_EnumObjects, MyEnumObjects))
    {
        PDEBUG(L". CoCreateInstance. Failed to set EnumObjects!");
    }else
    {
        PDEBUG(L". CoCreateInstance. success to set EnumObjects!");
    }
}
```

but it never go inside that if 
anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change to

```
if (IsEqualCLSID(rclsid, (REFGUID) CLSID_ShellFSFolder) )
```

and now it works

Answer (score 0):

The following lays out how the windows API enumerates files in a directory.  Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/371213/Enumerate-Files-in-a-directory-using-WIN32-API).

[EDIT]
Missed the intent of your question on my first entry.  You want to know how to trap an event when iShellFolder is accessed?  You have probably already [Looked Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff934858.aspx)?.  It has some example code, and discusses topics around what I think may be useful.

Comment: I was write that I already hook FindFirstFile (FindFirstFileEx) / FindNextFile / FindClose.  I don't want to use them! I wand to hook them. and in windows 7 windows explorer don't use them any more in every browse to specific directory

Comment: I don't want  to trap an event.  I want to replace the value that return by enumObjects